# Android Hilt and Retrofit with OkHttpOAuthConsumer

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, dagger-hilt

I am using `Hilt` and I am trying to create and inject a Retrofit client.

My problem is that one of my retrofit clients needs a `SigningInterceptor(consumer)` where my consumer (`OkHttpOAuthConsumer`) needs a `setTokenWithSecret(token, tokenSecret)`.

So my question is how can I pass information (token and tokenSecret) to `Hilt` while creating my Retrofit client.

Some code (may be clearer):

My `ApiModule.kt`:

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
@Module
object ApiModule {

    //used to change URL dynamically
    var url: String = "https://localhost"

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("unsigned")
    fun provideRetrofitClient(): Retrofit {
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        } else {
            interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
        }

        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build()

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
            .client(client)
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("signed")
    // The problem is here with those String
    fun getClient(token: String, tokenSecret: String): Retrofit {

        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        } else {
            interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
        }

        consumer = OkHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
        consumer.setTokenWithSecret(token, tokenSecret)
        
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(SigningInterceptor(consumer))
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build()

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
            .client(client)
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideLoginApi(
        @Named("unsigned") retrofit: Retrofit
    ): LoginApiInterface =
        retrofit.create(LoginApiInterface::class.java)


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUpdateDeviceApiInterface(
        @Named("signed") retrofit: Retrofit
    ): UpdateDeviceApiInterface =
        retrofit.create(UpdateDeviceApiInterface::class.java)

}
```

My `Repository`:

```
class MyRepository @Inject constructor(
    ...
    private var updateDeviceApiInterface: UpdateDeviceApiInterface,
    ...
) {
...
}
```

My `ViewModel`:

```
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private var myRepository: MyRepository
) :
    ViewModel() {
    ...
}
```

Finally my `Fragment`:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    ...
    @Inject
    lateinit var myViewModel: MyViewModel
    ...
}
```

(I have no problem with the first retrofit client `@Named(unsigned)` so no problem to use LoginApiInterface).

Comment: All will depend on where do you get these two strings from ? are they supposed to be hardcoded (I don't think so) ?
If you can't get them during app creation (i.e. received from server) you'll probably need to provide a singleton `OkHttpOAuthConsumer` instance to call setTokenWithSecret on it later once possible.

Comment: Hi @AchrafAmil thanks for your help. You are right I get them from the server so I will try your option (Singleton of OkHttpOAuthConsumer)